# Should @ComponentScan stay in the class containing the main method?

Tags: spring, component-scan

I know that @ComponentScan with @Configuration tell Spring where to look for beans.

```
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
public class MyApp{
     ...
}
```

What I do not understand is on which class I have to put these two annotations. Should they stay on the class containing the main method?
Like this

```
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
public class MyApp{

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          ...
     }

}
```

Or they can stay on whatever class of the application?
The question comes from the fact that Spring has to know the location of @ComponentScan... or is there an automatic way of detection of the @ComponentScan annotation which Spring is performing under the hood?
Hope to have explained myself!

Comment: you mean how does it decides which packages to scan?

Comment: Since several versions ago, by default, Spring will search in your project the classes annotated with `@Component` and children ones. So every time, `@ComponentScan` is used less frequently, only when you want/need specify where Spring has to search classes you want inject.

Comment: if Spring search for @Componet classes, why do I need to specify the location inside ComponentScan?

Answer (score 1):

You can put it wherever you want (I usually put mine in com.domain.project-name.config) and just specify the directories it should scan, for example if you want it to scan everything in project use

```
@ComponentScan("com.domain.project-name")
@Configuration
public class Config {
...
```

By default, ComponentScan scans all the annotated classes at the current directory level and below.

Comment: The question was a bit different. How does Spring know where is @ComponentScan? does it automatically look inside the entire project looking for @ComponentScan?

Answer (score 1):

`@Configuration` annotation tells the Spring container that the class contains Spring bean configuration.

`@ComponentScan` annotation tells the Spring container that the annotated class to scan/searches for other annotations and components. You can also define package name to scan with the annotation like `@ComponentScan("your.package.name")` or you can give package/class names that need not be scanned.

Hence, you can put these annotations on any class that defines your bean configuration and could be required by spring container to parse and create objects for your entities/POJOs, services and DAOs.

To conclude, I would like to add `@ComponentScan` and other annotations are there for automatic detection. Else, you would need to define XMLs (that's what happens under the hood with annotations) for spring to read and perform these actions.

Comment: The question was a bit different. How does Spring know where is @ComponentScan? does it automatically look inside the entire project looking for @ComponentScan?

Comment: @StefanoSambruna Every class you annotate with `@ComponentScan` gets its entry in `DispatcherServlet` as `<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.name" />`. The `DispatcherServlet` implements *Front Controller* design pattern and it is the first class that is loaded in the Spring container. Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using simple example. You can place `@ComponentScan` with `@Configuration` in any class which main method can scan.

> Main class scans MyScan class which then scan for bean class.

```
package com.boot.spring;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.boot.scan")
public class BootApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(BootApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println(ctx.getBean("demoBean"));
    }
}
```

Bean class is in different package

```
package com.boot.bean;
@Service
public class DemoBean {
}
```

Now, bean class is discovered through DemoScan class

```
package com.boot.scan;
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.boot.bean")
@Configuration
public class DemoScan {
}
```